# CSS: expand container div height according to the content whilst getting the inner div positioned at the bottom

Tags: css, position

I'd like to get my div element expanding according to the content, whilst having the content sticking to the bottom of the container.

I've came up with the following to stretch the container height, which is fine, but can't get the absolute position.
As soon as I absolutely position the inner div to the bottom, the inner content get positioned in a bad way.

```
        <div id="id1" class="subcontent-wrap2">
            <div class="innerTextBox2">
                <h3 class="title2">Title</h3>
                <div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur     adipiscing elit. Etiam fringilla turpis nisl, sit amet faucibus turpis egestas non. Phasellus est urna, dapibus a dignissim non, cursus in risus. Aenean eu lorem odio. Fusce bibendum tristique purus, id consectetur tellus posuere non. Phasellus consequat tincidunt dui, eu vestibulum odio venenatis sed. Proin convallis fermentum purus, ac tempus libero sollicitudin et. Sed vel risus vitae dui sollicitudin ornare. Proin accumsan eget magna non cursus. Nulla sollicitudin dapibus bibendum. Suspendisse eleifend suscipit lacus in suscipit. Nullam interdum massa vitae nisi viverra, in porta ante aliquet. Donec diam urna, euismod vel lacus vitae, sagittis fermentum orci. Phasellus dictum erat orci, dapibus volutpat dolor dictum non. Curabitur dignissim sagittis elementum. Sed facilisis consectetur mi sit amet vehicula. Aliquam lacus risus, eleifend ut accumsan sed, viverra ut eros. Fusce sem risus, sagittis ut lorem id, condimentum ultrices ante. Aliquam vitae orci quam. Integer nec mi nec magna pulvinar sodales ut nec ipsum. Nullam nec nisi quis erat dictum consectetur sed sed lorem. Vivamus sodales turpis tempus diam mollis, quis tempor turpis hendrerit. Sed luctus interdum euismod. Aliquam sed sapien dictum lorem dictum faucibus. Sed ut risus vestibulum, feugiat elit ut, euismod elit. Vestibulum hendrerit odio ullamcorper lacus vestibulum feugiat.
                </div>
                <img src="images/graphic.jpg" class="boxPic" alt="....">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.title2, .text2 { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; } 
.subcontent-wrap2 { width: 464px; min-height: 250px; height: auto; overflow: auto; position: relative; text-align: left; }
.innerTextBox2 { position: relative; width: 314px; left: 145px; border: 1px solid green; }
.boxPic { width: 140px; height: 250px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; border: 1px blue solid; }
.title2 { font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 20px; }
.text2 { font-size: 15px; color: #fff; line-height: 1.6em; position: absolute; bottom: 0; border: 1px solid purple; }
```

Whereas transforming the Inner div in absolute I can get the content align at the bottom, but as soon as the content is more than the container, the text overflow to the top without the container increasing its height.

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing `</div>` tag.  Does the image go inside `.innerTextBox2`? or inside `.subcontent-wrap2`?

Comment: My fault in copying an pasting here. The images is supposed to go inside the innerTextBox2 to be together with the content. I will be having many subcontent-wrap2 items.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like the following.

Start with this **HTML**:

```
<div id="id1" class="subcontent-wrap2">
    <div class="innerTextBox2">
        <h3 class="title2">Title</h3>
        <div class="text2">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x250" class="boxPic" alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

and try the following **CSS**:

```css
.title2, .text2 {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.subcontent-wrap2 {
    display: table;
    width: 464px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.innerTextBox2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.boxPic {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 140px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
.title2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.text2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 280px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rxKHT/

On the `.subcontent-wrap2` container, apply `display: table` and fix the width and height.  On a table, the height is taken to be a minimum value so the table will expand as needed once the content exceeds the preferred height.

For `.innerTextBox2`, use `display: table-cell`, and then `vertical-align: bottom` to get all the content to rest at the bottom of this container.

I was not sure how you wanted to place the image and the text, but I set `.text2` to be an inline-block with a width.  At the moment, the text is to the left of the image, but you wan move the image move the `.text2` block in the source code if you want the image to be to the right.

**Browser Compatibility**

The `display` value os  `table` and `table-cell` are part of CSS2.1 and are backwards compatible to IE8, see more details at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: so far the best solution, though I'm concerned about the table like implementation. Is this compatible and CSS3 like_

Comment: thanks. Looking how to move images on the left side, but seems this break the design by all mean.

Comment: I added a note regarding browser compatibility.  The use of `display: table-cell` is gaining in popularity since it takes care of many design problems related to vertical alignment.  The alternative is to use JavaScript/jQuery to adjust heights and positioning dynamically.

Comment: Cheers, see the note about the table cell. It's weird because it looks we are going toward the same direction we were used to be years go, with graphic align in HTML with table elements (bad implementation).

Comment: Here is one example showing how to position the image to the left: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rxKHT/3/

Comment: Years ago, tables were used to create a grid for an entire page.  That is very different from using an isolated table-cell block to get vertical alignment the way you need it.  A full-page table layout is clunky since the whole table needs to be build before the page can be rendered.  In contrast, a block using `display: table-cell` is more or less self-contained and will not slow down the rendering of your page.

Comment: Understood. As for the example. I got the same, but the title is then misaligned to the right. Let me play around with it.